# postgres sum different table columns from many to one joined data

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

Suppose I have the following two tables:

`foo`:

```
| id | goober | value |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | a1     | 25    |
| 2  | a1     | 125   |
| 3  | b2     | 500   |
```

`bar`:

```
| id | foo_id | value |
|----|--------|-------|
| 1  | 1      |  4    |
| 2  | 3      |  19   |
| 3  | 3      |  42   |
| 4  | 3      |  22   |
| 5  | 3      |  56   |
```

Note the n:1 relationship of `bar.foo_id : foo.id`.

My goal is to sum the `value` columns for tables `foo` and `bar`, joining on `bar.foo_id=foo.id`, and finally grouping by `goober` from `foo`.  Then performing a calculation if possible, though not critical.

Resulting in a final output looking something like:

```
| goober | foo_value_sum | bar_value_sum | foo_bar_diff |
|--------|---------------|---------------|--------------|
| a1     | 150           | 4             | 146          |
| b2     | 500           | 139           | 361          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be rather simple by the following query that creates two CTEs and then joins them afterwards:

```sql
with bar_agg as
(
    select foo.goober
    ,sum(bar.value) bar_value_sum
    from foo
    join bar
      on bar.foo_id = foo.id
    group by foo.goober
)
,foo_agg as 
(
    select foo.goober
    ,sum(foo.value) foo_value_sum
    from foo
    group by foo.goober
)
select foo.goober
,foo_value_sum
,bar_value_sum
,foo_value_sum - bar_value_sum foo_bar_diff
from foo_agg foo
left join bar_agg bar
  on bar.goober = foo.goober
order by foo.goober
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this result in `foo.value` getting multiplied by the number of `bar` rows that point to it?  In the example above, `foo_value_sum` for `goober=b2` would be `2000`?  Unless I'm not translating this correctly to my local context, that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: You are right - I overlooked this, let me edit my answer.

Comment: Works like a dream.  Thanks, appreciate it.